# WiX check on .NET 4.5 Framework always returns a value?

Tags: wix, .net-4.5

My goal is to show a popup that the .NET 4.5 framework is not available on the machine running the installer.

I have read through numerous posts about the .NET runtime check in WiX. In most of them I found what I needed:

```
PropertyRef: NETFRAMEWORK45
Condition: Installed or NETFRAMEWORK45
```

However, this condition never ends up being FALSE, thus not showing the message.
To "test" this I changed my:

```
InnerText:
Installed OR FALSE (could've been just FALSE as well to be fair)
Message: 
I will be shown: [NETFRAMEWORK45]
```

My test environment is a Windows 8 VMWare with almost nothing installed on it:

[image: VMWare Programs and Features]

The messagebox always results in:

```
I will be shown: #378389
```

PS: The Google for "Wix #378389" gave me three hits and the last one seemed to be useful but it's no longer available:

```
https://www.google.be/search?q=%23378389&oq=%23378389&aqs=chrome..69i57.154j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=wix+%23378389
```

Summary:

- How do I use this NETFRAMEWORK45 PropertyRef? Ie, what am I doing wrong?
- General tips are also welcome

If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 comes with .NET 4.5 installed by default. That's why NETFRAMEWORK45 returns a value: It's the internal release value of .NET 4.5.

Comment: Oh my ... I actually did not consider that something would be included in Windows by default and that it would not be shown in the Add or Remove Programs.
Thanks a bunch for pointing out, what is apparently, the obvious!

I will create a VMWare tonight with Windows 7 and I'll mark your answer as accepted once my test passes.

Comment: On Windows 7 I do get the popup. Answer accepted, thanks again!